# Xamarin Forms Native embedding Memory issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use Xamarin Forms pages in a Xamarin IOS Native app. To do that I am using the CreateViewController. The issue I am facing is that every time I push a new view controller, memory are allocated that are not released when I click on the back button. This results in that the app will crash. Is this the wrong way to do it?

```
var _historyViewController = new HistoryPage().CreateViewController();
// And push it onto the navigation stack
_navigation.PushViewController(_historyViewController, true);
```

Link to code: https://github.com/toupilsner/XamarinFormsEmbedded/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Have you tried to do it like the Microsoft example, where you are reusing the view controller instead of recreating each time, otherwise you would need to show the code that you are using to clean up/dispose of that vc instance after you are done with it.

Comment: "Have you tried to do it like the Microsoft example, where you are reusing the view controller instead of recreating each time" -> yes, I have, but I do not want to reuse it because it will not remove the original memory footprint. If I have a big image in that viewconroller, it will take approx 50 mb of memory. If I do that to many vc, this will lead to memory leak.

I do not cleanup that viewcontroller manually, since I am removing it from the navigationstack, it should be GC since there is no reference to it in the ios navigation stack.

Comment: `...it should be GC...` GC'd by what? Now I have no idea of your actual code, but those are native allocations via the ObjC runtime and if you are not disposing of those native allocs via Mono and then releasing those allocs from within your ObjC/Swift code that is originally calling the embedded Mono library, you will leak memory.